# ¿Cómo resolver un laberinto en javascript usando recursividad?

Tags: javascript, recursión

La función debe retornar un string de los movimientos Norte(N), Sur(S), Este(E), Oeste(O)
que se deben realizar, para llegar al destino de un laberinto dado.

El retorno de la funcion 'direcciones' debe ser 'SEN', ya que el destino se encuentra
haciendo los movimientos SUR->ESTE->NORTE
Aclaraciones: el segundo parametro que recibe la funcion ('direccion') puede ser pasado vacio (null)
Gracias por su ayuda :)

```
let lab = { 
      // direccion = ""
         N: 'pared', // 'pared'
         S: { // direccion = "S"
             N: 'pared',
             S: 'pared',
             E: { // direccion = "SE"
                 N: 'destino', // direccion = "SEN"
                 S: 'pared',
                 E: 'pared',
                 O: 'pared'
            },
             O: { // direccion = "SO"
                 N: 'pared',
                 S: 'pared',
                 E: 'pared',
                 O: 'pared'
             }
         },
         E: 'pared',
         O: 'pared'
     }
     
    
    
    function direcciones(lab) {
      let aux = []
      for(const [clave, valor] of Object.entries(lab)) {
         if(lab.N === 'destino') {
           aux.push('N')
           return aux
         }
        
        if(lab.S === 'destino') {
           aux.push('S')
           return aux
         }
        
        if(lab.E === 'destino') {
           aux.push('E')
           return aux
         }
        
        if(lab.O === 'destino') {
           aux.push('O')
           return aux
         }
        
        if(lab.N !== 'laberinto' && lab.S !== 'laberinto' && lab.E !== 'laberinto' && lab.O !== 'laberinto') {
           aux.push('O')
           return aux;
         }
        
        
         if(typeof valor === 'object') {
           return direcciones(valor)
    
          }
      
        }
      
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `recursión` para implementar tu algoritmo. La idea es que vas a recorrer tu objeto de manera iterativa desde los nodos más externos hasta los más internos. En cuanto encuentres la palabra `destino`, el algoritmo se detendrá retornando la clave del objeto más interno. Al recibir una clave, el objeto más externo agregará también su clave, y así sucesivamente hasta llegar a la raíz y tener la ruta completa.

Cabe notar que en esta implementación el algoritmo asume que existe un solo `destino`. Si existe más de un `destino` el algoritmo devolverá la ruta al primero que encuentre. Si no existe ningún destino, devolverá una cadena vacía.

```js
let lab = {
    // direccion = ""
    N: 'pared', // 'pared'
    S: { // direccion = "S"
        N: 'pared',
        S: 'pared',
        E: { // direccion = "SE"
            N: 'destino', // direccion = "SEN"
            S: 'pared',
            E: 'pared',
            O: 'pared' // direccion = "SEO"
        },
        O: { // direccion = "SO"
            N: 'pared',
            S: 'pared',
            E: 'pared',
            O: 'pared'
        }
    },
    E: 'pared',
    O: 'pared'
}

function direcciones(laberinto) {
    for (const [clave, valor] of Object.entries(laberinto)) {
        if (valor === 'destino') {
            return clave;
        }

        if (typeof valor === 'object') {
            let destinoEncontrado = direcciones(valor);
            if (destinoEncontrado.length > 0) {
                return clave + destinoEncontrado;
            }
        }
    }

    return '';
}

console.log(direcciones(lab));
```

Comment: Gracias bro! excelente

Comment: ¿Por que se da  que al recibir una clave, el objeto más externo agregará también su clave?  ¿ es algo que hubiera podido intuir o no ? es que no esperaba ese comportamiento del código

Comment: Si la función devuelve una clave, significa que encontró el destino, por tanto, debo investigar la manera en que llegué hasta ese lugar. Para ello la función retorna el control al nivel superior, el nivel superior agrega la clave que lo identifica y pasa al inmediatamente superior, así hasta llegar a la raíz y tener la ruta completa al destino. Si la función no encuentra el destino, nunca devuelve nada que no sea una cadena vacía, y por tanto no devuelve nunca una ruta. Intenta depurar el programa en vscode o webstorm para que comprendas mejor como funciona.

Comment: Eso are bro, Muchas gracias!